# Service Reference: HTTP Status 404- Metadata contains a reference that cannot be resolved

Tags: c#, web-services, soap, wsdl, soap-client

I am trying to connect to the California tax rate public API in my C# console application and receiving the service reference error below.  I have been using it successfully for about 9 months.  I tried to recreate the reference in a new application but receive the same error.  I am unsure what troubleshooting steps to take.  Please let me know if I can provide any more useful information.

The service is located here and is public to test: http://services.gis.boe.ca.gov/api/taxrates/Rates.svc

> There was an error downloading
> 'http://services.gis.boe.ca.gov/api/taxrates/Rates.svc/$metadata'. The
> request failed with HTTP status 404: Not Found. Metadata contains a
> reference that cannot be resolved:
> 'http://services.gis.boe.ca.gov/api/taxrates/Rates.svc'. The server
> did not provide a meaningful reply; this might be caused by a contract
> mismatch, a premature session shutdown or an internal server error. If
> the service is defined in the current solution, try building the
> solution and adding the service reference again.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

the wsdl that you get from the endpoint is invalid.

```
<xs:element name="TestResponse">
  <xs:element minOccurs="0" maxOccurs="1" name="TestResult" type="xs:string"/>          
</xs:element>
```

should be

```
<xs:element name="TestResponse">
    <xs:complexType>
        <xs:sequence>
            <xs:element minOccurs="0" maxOccurs="1" name="TestResult" type="xs:string"/>
        </xs:sequence>
    </xs:complexType>
</xs:element>
```

and the same for

```
<xs:element name="GetRateResponse">
    <xs:element minOccurs="0" maxOccurs="1" name="GetRateResult" type="tns:CARateResponseCollection"/>
</xs:element>
```

also

```
<wsdl:message name="ISoapService_Test_OutputMessage">
    <wsdl:part name="parameters" element="tns:String"/>
</wsdl:message>
```

should be

```
<wsdl:message name="ISoapService_Test_OutputMessage">
  <wsdl:part name="parameters" element="tns:TestResponse"/>
</wsdl:message>
```

and last

```
<wsdl:message name="ISoapService_GetRate_OutputMessage">
    <wsdl:part name="parameters" element="tns:CARateResponseCollection"/>
</wsdl:message>
```

must be

```
<wsdl:message name="ISoapService_GetRate_OutputMessage">
        <wsdl:part name="parameters" element="tns:GetRateResponse/>
</wsdl:message>
```

Comment: Brilliant! But how do I resolve this on the client?  Or do I need to have the service update the WSDL?

Comment: the wsdl needs to be updated server side so it is correct. then you need to update the client using the new wsdl to match.

Answer (score 0):

Here is the code I used @Rihab Berrich.  I don't recall exactly what the issue was but hoping this will help you and anyone else who stumbles across this.

```
string apiParams = $"?address={AddressLine1.Replace(' ', '+')}&city={City.Replace(' ', '+')}&zip={PostalCode.Replace(' ', '+')}";
string endPoint = $"https://services.maps.cdtfa.ca.gov/api/taxrate/GetRateByAddress{apiParams}";
RestClient client = new(endPoint) { Timeout = 30000 };

RestRequest request = new();
request.AddHeader("Cookie", "TiPMix=28.368612388085868; x-ms-routing-name=self");
IRestResponse response = client.Execute(request);
CATax cATax = JsonConvert.DeserializeObject<CATax>(response.Content);
```

And here is the CATax data model class

```
public class CATaxModel
{
    public class CATax
    {
        public Taxrateinfo[] TaxRateInfo { get; set; }
        public Geocodeinfo GeocodeInfo { get; set; }
        public string TermsOfUse { get; set; }
        public string Disclaimer { get; set; }
    }

    public class Geocodeinfo
    {
        public string[] MatchCodes { get; set; }
        public string FormattedAddress { get; set; }
        public string Confidence { get; set; }
        public string CalcMethod { get; set; }
        public int BufferDistance { get; set; }
    }

    public class Taxrateinfo
    {
        public decimal Rate { get; set; }
        public string Jurisdiction { get; set; }
        public string City { get; set; }
        public string County { get; set; }
        public string Tac { get; set; }
    }
}
```